# Why is IDMF not supported on AX 2012 R3

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax

I see that IDMF was released today and it's supported for every 2012 version barring R3.

Is there another product that'll take it's place?

Is the development team still working on the R3 version?

Comment: I think it may be that MDM is replacing IDMF. Can't find anything official to support this theory however

Comment: MDM (Master Data Management) is based on the DIXF (Data Import Export Framework) and has nothing to do with the IDMF (Intelligent Data management Framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments to the blog entry [Microsoft Dynamics AX Intelligent Data Management Framework 2.0 released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/axsa/archive/2014/07/21/idmf-2-0.aspx) they are working on an update for R3 and plan to release it in mid September.